# configure mysite different Web application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, my-site

I have already a web application with this url

```
http://sp.blah.com
```

is it possible to have mysite on differet web application but following url?

```
 http://sp.blah.se/my
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.

In fact it's generally recommended to use a seperate web app for my sites as it's common for this to end up being mysite for multiple web applications.

For more information see: [Plan for My Sites](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edf74cf-8808-4277-ba10-b1f925d7c440) and [Set up My Sites](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624362.aspx)

Comment: Yes, what I wanted to know was the url of my site .../my. I tested to create a mysite to use above url but I got an error, something like wrong url.

Comment: In order to get the start of mysites as `http://sp.blah.se/my` you need to first create the web application `http://sp.blah.se`, then create some site collection at the root, create an explicit managed path of `my` create a my site host at that managed path and set up user profile service to point at it